# Situations when you can need a Webusercontrol?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

I'm making a small application where you can add and delete movies etc. Now i'm supposed to add a Webusercontrol to my webpage (yes this is schoolwork). Do you have any smart situations where you need a webusercontrol? Not a menu because I have made that in my masterpage alreay.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere you need to reuse the same UI logic over and over again, is one good reason to do so.  Or if you just need to break up the length of the page so it isn't so large from a visual perspective, that can sometimes be a reason to do so too.

A user control is a container, so you can contain grouped logic together.  A menu can be a user control so the logic around it is grouped together, but doesn't have to be.

There is no hard and fast rule.